# Making additional changes to manuscript after the refereeing process is completed

Tags: publications, paper-submission

After doing some revision to my paper to include changes suggested by the referee (who will not see the paper again, having recommended the paper for publication), is it OK for me to make a minor change of my own, in the manuscript (before I send it to the editor)? Should I declare this in the list of changes or should I wait till the paper is officially accepted for publication by the journal? Would it then be up to the editor to check the validity of the slightly changed statement?

(I've noticed something minor in the manuscript, which needs to be fixed - and amounts to changing a couple of words in the comments section).

Answer (score 5):

I always make minor edits (unrelated to the reviewer comments) at the time of doing revisions, and make a comment in the response letter, e.g. "we have also made minor changes to improve the readability of section 4.2." It's in the interests of the journal to have a well-written article.

Depending on the journal, you will probably also have a chance to make very minor revisions during the copyediting process.